# Почему "керосинить"?

Tags: этимология

Один из, так сказать, народных эпитетов слова "пить" (алкоголь) — "керосинить". А откуда пошло это выражение и при чем тут керосин?
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому, что керосин пить можно. Точнее, лучше конечно не пить, но пьют и опьянение он вызывает. Лётчики и прочие имеющие с ним дело, в советское время, а порой и сейчас керосинили вполне в прямом смысле, т. е. пили керосин. Отсюда скорей всего и выражение.

Answer (score 1):

С керосином связано напрямую: керосин - топливо для авиации, без него вертолёт не полетит, алкоголь - топливо для пьяницы, алкоголика, без него он не живёт, а подзаправился - и "полетел"... Метафора получается.  Керосинить(арго) - потреблять алкоголь, заправляться алкогольным топливом как жизненной энергией.